# View the settings window for the Kate Editor

Tags: kate

I'm running Kubuntu 22.04. I'm trying to change the text size in the Kate Editor, and I've encountered two problems:

1. I can't see all of the settings window (Configure Kate), and I can't change its size.  Is this the ten-year-old Bug 9632657?
2. I changed the size of the editor font from 7 to 13, but the change was ineffective.  That might be because the button for confirming the change was in the truncated part of the window.

Comment: What OS and version?

Comment: It's Kubuntu 22.04. I've modified the question to reflect that.

Comment: alt+a for apply changes in settings. maybe an enter after that. have you tried changing your display resolution by way of experimentation?